# Async/Await returning result not promise

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm very confused with async/await. I've been reading answers on s/o but I do not understand if async/await actually does what I want.

I'm trying to return the result of an async call in a synchronous way and maybe that's why I fail, maybe it's not made for that? I do not want to return a callback (or promise) but the result of one.

Here's what I've been trying to do

```
 let namespace = {};

 namespace.Test = class{

      constructor(){

      }        


      async get(){
           let response = await this._load();       
           let data = await response;
           console.log(data); //Logs my data but return Promise instead
           return data;  
      }

     _load(){
         let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {       
             fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then(function(response){
                resolve(response.json());                
            }).catch(error =>  reject(error));           
         });
         return promise;
     }

  }


  //The goal is to figure out if I can have that
  let myTest = new namespace.Test();
  //Here I want data NOT a promise
  let res = myTest.get();

  console.log(res); //logs a Promise but I want what has been resolved instead
```

I thought resolving the promise inside _load and then using await inside get would do that?

Comment: async functions return a promise right away, and that promise is resolved when they reach a `return`. There’s no going back, sorry. :)

Comment: Shouldn't `this._load()` point to `load()` in the constructor which is empty or before constructor as private?

Comment: @zer00ne no I don't want the class to load at start

Comment: @Eric you only have a single thread, which is a design choice that has a lot of benefits, but also some drawbacks. One of the drawbacks is that you need to decide how to handle asynchronous things. JS has made the choice to not block the thread, which is almost certainly the right choice 99% of the time. It makes things a little less convenient sometimes, but it's not that hard once you get used to it.

Comment: have you tried new getter syntax? `get async retrieve() {...` not 100% about the `async` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to return the result of an async call in a synchronous way

That's impossible. The only thing that is synchronously returned by an async function is a promise (all async functions return promises, by design). Async functions make the syntax for working with promises easier, but they're still asynchronous.

When you use `await` inside your async function, this will delay how long it takes for the returned promise to resolve. This is good: if any code is waiting on that promise, it will wait longer, and thus will hold off until your async function is completely done. But waiting for the promise is not automatic; you either need to use the promise's `.then` method, or need to use the `await` keyword inside an `async` function.

```
let resPromise = myTest.get();
resPromise.then(res => console.log(res));
```

```
async someFunction() {
  const res = await myTest.get();
  console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Then async/await is completely stupid? Why name something "await" which indicates sementically to WAIT before you return and have it do something else? Am I missing the point?

Comment: The purpose of it is to make the syntax for working with promises easier. While you're inside an async function, the syntax looks a lot more like linear synchronous code (as compared to .then callbacks), which can be easier to follow. But it's still asynchronous, and it's still using promises. Generally, code that uses promises is infectious: if one function uses promises, then anything that depends on it will need to use promises as well.

Comment: @Eric Yes, the point you're missing is that the purpose of `async-await` is to make the syntax *inside* the async function more readable. It makes it possible to work with asynchronous processes without having to nest and chain `then()` callbacks. Everything outside of the async function is completely agnostic about what goes on inside the function. It doesn't matter, it's still an async function so it returns a promise regardless. It's definitely not stupid.

Comment: "More readable" is what I hear, so it's just semantics for coders? Which is stupid because I can read my own code back... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, you hear correctly. The purpose is to make it more readable (and writeable). With or without async functions, javascript is still single threaded and uses callbacks as its mechanism for resuming after async work is completed. Promises are an abstraction on top of callbacks, and async/await is an abstraction on top of promises. If you don't find async/await useful, that's fine: you can use promises in the raw or callbacks in the raw. But those are your options for doing async things. Synchronously returning async values is not an option in javascript.

Comment: @Eric Yes it's just semantics. Syntactic sugar. If it's stupid, then all programming languages are stupid because they're just syntactic sugar for a sequence of ones and zeros.

Comment: @Lennholm too far dude. Nicholas, well promises are only useful if the result of a callback has effects on subsequent callbacks. If I have one callback only, I do not need promises, it's in the definition. Thanks I will close this question.

Comment: @Eric Promises are useful to make the code more readable, even with a single callback. You can accomplish everything you can do with promises by simply nesting callbacks, you'll just end up with very messy and unreadable code.

Answer (score 1):

as `fetch()` already return a promise, there is no reason to wrap it in another promise.

```
 _load(){ return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')}
```

Comment: I do not want to return a promise!!! I'm trying to return when a promise has been resolved...

Comment: @Eric isn't it your question about how to return a promise?

Comment: @OlegI, not it's about returning when a promise has been resolved using async/await

Comment: async is all about managing promises mate. If you do not return a `Promise()` there will be nothing to `await` for.

Comment: You are missing the whole point of the question @MosèRaguzzini

Comment: No, I understand perfectly your code. It returns a promise because you are returning a `Promise()` (where await act) and INSIDE that `Promise()` you return another one (fetch())

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but to do so, fetch() alone will suffice. If you mange promises with .then().catch(). There are no valid reason to await.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Nah, he's trying to return an asynchronous value synchronously. He wants the `get()` method to return the value immediately instead of returning a promise. In other words, he's trying to perform time travel.

Comment: @Lennholm it's not time travel when I specifically use "await" to return. I'm just waiting for it!

Comment: He want to return a promise resolving it when another promise is returned by fetch. Theoretically is possible, but still has no sense vs await on `fetch()`

Comment: @Eric But there's no concept of "waiting" for something in synchronous JS, it only exists *inside* a scope that has been explicitly annotated to be asynchronous JS

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini No, that's not what he wants. He doesn't want the `get()` method to return a promise at all, he wants it to return the actual resolved value which is impossible since that doesn't get resolved until some time after this line of code has been executed and moved on from.

Comment: @Lennholm sorry but my brain refuses to think it ahah

Answer (score -1):

We can try this by specifying async in Self invoking function globally,

```js
(async function() {
let namespace2 = {};

 namespace2.Test = class{

      constructor(){

      }        


      async get(){
           let response = await this._load();       
           let data = await response;
           console.log(data); //Logs my data but return Promise instead
           return data;  
      }

     _load(){
         let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {       
             fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then(function(response){
                resolve(response.json());                
            }).catch(error =>  reject(error));           
         });
         return promise;
     }

  }



  //The goal is to figure out if I can have that
  let myTest2 = new namespace2.Test();
  //Here I want data NOT a promise
  let res2 = await myTest2.get();

  console.log(res2);
})();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do this by `await` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

So you just write:

```js
//Here I want data NOT a promise
let res = await myTest.get();
```

And `console.log(res);` will now return the resolved value.

Comment: But it does not? await is only valid in async functions and async generators

Comment: @Eric Exactly, it's not possible to await something in synchronous JS since it would mean blocking the entire single thread that JS runs on, which is not an option.